# How to treat different status quo groups in a choice experiment?

Tags: regression, stata, choice-modeling

I have a choice experiment where respondents choose between a status quo and one alternative. Before the choice questions, respondents are allocated to four different groups which determine the levels of their attributes they see in their status quo option. But, of course, for the status quo, these attribute levels does not change across choice sets for a specific respondent.

How do I treat these different groups? Can I estimate the model including the data of all different status quo groups or do I have to estimate all groups separately?

Comment: with no answer, i would go for estimating all groups separately OR, since you probably have a dummy variable per group, i would consider that the information related to the specificities of each status quo can be dealt within a unique model.